# Inject code via @annotation. Java

Tags: java, annotations, inject, code-injection

Suppose you have a method somewhere like this:

```java
public square(int x){
    return Math.square(x);
}
```

and suppose you want to make an annotatiom to inject the method in here:

```java
int x=2
@Square(x)
int y;
```

so your code ends like:

```java
int x=2
int y=square(x);
```

Is it posible and how?

Comment: In your particular example, in Java, only during compilation with an annotation processor. You can't do it at runtime. But you may want to look at AspectJ.

Comment: Also, maybe this is just a very simplified example, but what do you want to gain by doing this?

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis, yes, it is for compile time

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis im tryin to implement it for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195959/java-translatable-by-locale-class-best-approach